# Confusion matrix in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

If you look at this:

```
>>> y_true = ["cat", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "bird"]
>>> y_pred = ["ant", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "cat"]
>>> confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=["ant", "bird", "cat"])
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2]])
```

I suppose fist row of array means "predicted ant" and first column is "actually is ant" second column is "actually is bird" etc.

So first row first col 2 i read like "predicted ant, is ant", first row second col 0 i read as "precited ant is bird" is 0 which fits, and third column is "predicted ant is cat" is 0 but should be 1.

What i am doing wrong while understanding the confusion matrix.

Another example is this

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
>>> y_true = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1]
>>> y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2]
>>> confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2]])
```

Where is not even clear, what is the order of classes.

Source: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

**edit**: Unless it is swapped. First row is "is ant" not "predicted ant". Only that on wikipedia the system is that row is the prediction.

Comment: Did you see this line in [the docs you linked to](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)? "Returns: ... Confusion matrix whose i-th row and j-th column entry indicates the number of samples with true label being i-th class and prediced label being j-th class". And also "Wikipedia and other references may use a different convention for axes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just confused the actual and predicted. Every row represents actual values of distinct elements in your array and columns represent predicted values of them. That is,

[image]

- First row: There are 2 *ant*s, and 2 samples are predicted as *ant*.
- Seconds row: There are 1 *bird* and 1 sample is predicted as *cat*.
- Third row: There are 3 *cat*s, 1 sample is predicted as *ant*, 2 samples are predicted as *cat*.

Comment: yes, only that on wikpiadie the rows are the predictions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

Comment: Yes, axes of actual and predicted are always used interchangeably in the confusion matrix (My observations say it depends on the field). So it is always better to read the documentation first.